# How can I optimize this macro I compiled in excel 2010 for 2016?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have a Macro that searches for a string and when it finds it it copy and pastes values and formats with it.

It runs pretty slowly in 2016, certainly 2010. I haven't been able to figure out how to work around it.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strsearch As String, lastline As Long, tocopy As Long

    strsearch = CStr(InputBox("enter the string to search for"))
    lastline = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    J = 190

    For i = 1 To lastline
        For Each c In Range("G" & i & ":Z" & i)
            If InStr(c.Text, strsearch) Then
                tocopy = 1
            End If
        Next c 

        If tocopy = 1 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
            Sheets("Report").Range("A" & J).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
            Sheets("Report").Range("A" & J).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
            J = J + 1
        End If

        tocopy = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How much data do you typically have?

Comment: I'm not sure what difference you think the version of Excel is making, but [`.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) is probably going to be better than looping through all the rows for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would use the Range.Find method in lieu of the For Each loop to locate and select each instance of strSearch and then move your values and formats.

Comment: Tim, between 30-100 rows. Thank you everyone for your input so far

Comment: Just an aside for my own knowledge...does Instr() automatically yield a Boolean True when set up like this? My understanding was that it reported the position of the substring within the full string. So greater than 0 equates to a Boolean True?

Comment: @MBB70 `InStr` yields an index representing the position of the substring, if found. `-1` (or is it `0`? I can never remember...) if not found.

Comment: Use `Find` and use offset range to compare it with. to save time save the matches in array, and then copy the entire array at once to your `"Report"` sheet

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It is `0`: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php

Comment: @Mathieu Yes, that makes sense...I think it is 0. What I'm getting at though is from now on I can just type `If Instr(string, substring) Then...` in my conditionals instead of `If Instr(string, substring) > 0 Then...`

Comment: @MBB70 that's obscuring the returned data type and contributing to the confusion about exactly what `InStr` returns though, making it read like it's a Boolean. Implicit code is evil.

Comment: Agreed. I do prefer the explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work quickly for you:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim sFind As String
    Dim sFirst As String

    sFind = InputBox("Enter the string to search for:")
    If Len(sFind) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Report")

    With wsData.Range("G1:Z" & wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set rFind = .Find(sFind, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFind.Address
            Set rCopy = rFind
            Do
                Set rCopy = Union(rCopy, rFind)
                Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            Loop While rFind.Address <> sFirst

            Intersect(rCopy.Parent.Range("A:F"), rCopy.EntireRow).Copy
            wsDest.Range("A190").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsDest.Range("A190").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I appreciate everyone's contribution.